# Database user does not have enough privileges While running Setup Upgrade command in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database

I have freshly installed Magento 2.3.5p2 on the XAMPP server on Windows OS. It was working fine but then suddenly it's showing below the message.

> Database user does not have enough privileges. Please make sure
> SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE
> TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, C REATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW,
> CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, TRIGGER privileges are granted to
> database 'm235s'.

I have done changes to the my.ini MySQL file. and added

> skip-grant-tables

I have done changes in the apache configuration from localhost to 127.0.0.1

But still showing
[image]

What is the correct approach to solve this?

Comment: Note: I am not able to access the root user of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It's mysql privilege problem.

In your command line enter

> mysql -u root -p

then

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY
> 'password';

Comment: I think your command is not well formatted
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON m235s.* to 'your_db_user'@'%';`